# How to add a third language in PHP?

Tags: php

How to add a third language with this specific code format? I have successfully managed 2 languages. I would like to add more than 3 languages. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    else if (!isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
         if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
             $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
         else if ($_GET['lang'] == "sp")
             $_SESSION['lang'] = "sp";}
```

Comment: Hi Chloe!  Why don't you have a look at switch() statements in PHP and see if that helps you? https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Hello @Rory, I have read the switch statements in PHP but we are currently working on studying this structure. 

My next assignment will be the switch structure which is pretty easier than the array

Comment: As you already have an `else if` clause, just add another to cater for your third language. And another for your fourth, and so on. By the time you have five or six you'll want to get on to `switch()`.

Comment: @droopsnoot Why is it better to use switch() if we get to big amount of languages?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You can add a third language exactly the same way you added a second one.

Comment: Switch is just neater syntax and easier to read usually, than lots of else/if statements, that's all. Nothing to do with languages specifically, it's true for any kind of decision point in your code.

Comment: Another plus for `switch()` is I think it looks neater with multiple values - just having several `case` lines at the top of a single block of code looks nicer (to me) than an `else if` with a lot of conditions or-ed together. But you need to know about both, because `switch()` isn't always better than `if-else`.